# Strike through NSAttributedString: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Can anybody tell me what's wrong ?

```
let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: Xdevices[row].deviceName!,
              attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 
              15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.orangeColor(), 
              NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle])
```

The error is:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

This happened after inserting `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor(),
    NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(integer: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue)
]

let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: Xdevices[row].deviceName!, attributes: attributes)
```

`NSAttributedString(string:attributes:)` expects a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]`. Howeverm `StyleSingle` is an `Int`. Hence you must wrap it inside an `NSNumber`.

Comment: The issue is that `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle` is a Swift enum which doesn't conform to the AnyObject protocol. It is sufficient to just use `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue` which is an `Int` and Swift will convert that to an `NSNumber` for you.